# Creating an Iterable with values from a different Iterator / Iterable

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

I've written a ADT Sorted BinaryTree with the function:

```
public Iterator<T> getInorderIterator(){
    return new InorderIterator();
}
```

Which works, traverses the tree in order.

I then have a dictionary class that uses this class to store entries of type `Entry<K, V>`, and a function to return an Iterable of all the entries.

```
public Iterable<Entry<K, V>> entries() {
    //bST is BinarySortedTree
    return () -> bST.getInorderIterator();
}
```

All this works like it should, but I want to write 2 more functions that returns an Iterable of keys and values in the dictionary.  How would I create those Iterables from either the Iterable returned from `entries()` or from calling `getInorderIterator()` on the BinaryTree.

Entry class:

```
public class Entry<K, V> {
    public final K key;
    public final V value;

    public Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Entry) {
            Entry other = (Entry)o;
            return this.key.equals(other.key) && this.value.equals(other.value);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can not write the iterator within the BinaryTree class as it uses abstract data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just with the standard library, you can do

```
StreamSupport.stream(entries().spliterator(), false).map(entry -> entry.value).iterator()
```

for the values (obvious change for keys). I don't know if Java 9 or 10 have a simpler way to do it.

With [Apache Collection Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils.html)

```
IteratorUtils.transformedIterator(bST.getInorderIterator(), entry -> entry.value)
```